# Maximum average Manhattan distance to nearest neighbor

Tags: geometry

When you place points on a plane and measure the Manhattan distance for each point to its closest other point, what is the maximum average distance you can get for $n$ points?

For example, if we have $2$ points on a $15 * 15$ plane, we can place both points in opposite corners and have a distance of $15 + 15$ for both points to the other, thus an average distance of $15$. This is the maximum value we can get, and hence it is the maximum average distance for $2$ points.

The cases where $2 \leq n \leq 5$ are [visualized here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K0x6i.png). It seems that for the first few rounds, we simply divide the circumference by the number of points (i.e. the maximum average distance is $\frac{60}{n}$). For $n = 5$ however, we gain a free place to put a point.

My questions:

1. What is the formula behind this?
2. How does this translate to higher dimensions?
3. How do we continue placing points such that the average distance is maximum?

Answer (score 1):

I believe your question is related to packing, e.g.,

> van Dam, Edwin R. "Two-dimensional minimax Latin hypercube designs." *Discrete Applied Mathematics* 156, no. 18 (2008): 3483-3493.
>   [Journal link](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0166218X08000838).
>
> ---
>
> [image]
>   
>             
>   
>   <sup>Fig.4 (detail).</sup>

---